# Передача данных между страницами в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть проект в нем два файла, в одном файле есть текстбокс и кнопка по нажатию на которую переходит на другую страницу допустим с `MainPage` на `FirstPage`.

Мне надо как-то знать значение текстбокса на второй странице и обрабатывать их там уже. Мысли которые у меня были:

1. Добавить в App.xaml.Cs (самый главный файл) переменную и в неё записать и потом взять из неё уже в другом классе.
2. Записать в переменную в первом классе и из второго обратиться к первому.
3. Использовать базу данных (не пробовал).

Первые два не получились, третий не пробовал. Подскажите как бы сделали вы и почему.

Comment: App.html.Cs? Может App.xaml.cs ?

Comment: RussCoder, да вы правы просто раньше много работал с html, вот и перепутал.

Comment: MVVM и только MVVM. Ваше текстовое поле должно быть в вашей VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, вот самый простой вариант и достаточно культурный (можно конечно завести статическое поле и работать через него, или использовать словари ресурсов, или еще что-нибудь в этом роде, но не стоит). Добавьте в конструктор страницы доп. параметр и передавайте его при переходе:

```
public FirstPage(string txt = "") // конструктор страницы
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //работаем с txt
}
```

Код обработчика клика:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    /* передаем параметр при переходе */
    //this.NavigationService.Navigate(new FirstPage(mytextbox.Text)); // если обработчик вызвается внутри класса страницы
    this.Frame.Navigate(new FirstPage(mytextbox.Text)); // иной способ
 }
```

Comment: Ваш вариант мне очень нравится, но this.NavigationService.Navigate(new FirstPage(mytextbox.Text));
 у меня не работает, возможно нужно что-то подключить? Я использовал в своей программе раньше: this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

Comment: @Илит я думал у вас кнопка лежит внутри страницы и обработчик тамже. Иначе можно сделать как вы, только передавать надо страницу, а не ее тип. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @Илит пожалуйста.

Comment: Опять проблема, он не может преобразовать в системный тип когда передаю с аргументом: new FirstPage(mytextbox.Text), если без него то работает(new FirstPage). В FirstPage написал всё так же. Я думаю это переделать через хранение данных на устройстве и тогда всё будет _мне_ легче

Comment: показать сложно наверно будет, но из того что я понимаю он хочет чтобы в this.Frame.Navigate(тут) в скобках был тип Sustem.Type а не страница и он не может преобразовать

Comment: @Илит Frame это имя фрейма вашего? Лучше сменить конечно, так как совпадает с типом. Требовать `Type` он не может. У вас вообще при передаче типа переход происходил? Код можно показывать правя свой вопрос

Comment: Честно говоря я не совсем понимаю где это посмотреть и тогда я наверно займусь более хорошим изучением как всё это работает после чего перейду к решению этой задачи. Спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: @Илит да почитать определенно вам стоит. Но что касается имен контролов, то он прописаны в xaml разметке - cвойства `Name` или `x:Name`. Если объявить эти имена, то у вас в классе старницы будут доступны соответсвующие переменные.